# MySql in python script : Not enough parameters for the sql statement

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having hard time finding what's wrong with the following query in my python script.
I got the following message : "Not enough parameters for the sql statement".

The query and a piece of the code:

```
sql_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO events_fb (event_url, url, title, address_1, address_2, event_by, 
        start_time, end_time, ticket, going, interested, event_image_url, createdAt, image_path, description) VALUES (
        %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time=%s, end_time=%s, event_image_url=%s, description=%s, title=%s"""

data_tuple = (event_url, url, title, address_1, address_2, event_by, start_time, end_time, ticket, going, interested, event_image_url, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), output_path, description)
cursor.execute(sql_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
```

It's messing with the part **"ON DUPLICATE KEY"** but works well without that part.

The primary key is : **"url"**

Thanks

Comment: You have 20 `%s` in your query template, but only 15 values in your tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to update the new values ij the ROw use VALUES

Or add parameters for the paceholderd

```
sql_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO events_fb (event_url, url, title, address_1, address_2, event_by, 
        start_time, end_time, ticket, going, interested, event_image_url, createdAt, image_path, description) VALUES (
        %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time=VALUES(start_time), end_time=VALUES(end_time), event_image_url=VALUES(event_image_url), description=(description), title=VALUES(title)"""

data_tuple = (event_url, url, title, address_1, address_2, event_by, start_time, end_time, ticket, going, interested, event_image_url, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), output_path, description)
cursor.execute(sql_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add parameters for

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE start_time=%s, end_time=%s, event_image_url=%s, description=%s, title=%s
```